# UITableView reload cells' view

Tags: iphone, uitableview, reload

How can I reload the whole tableview? In `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` I'm comparing data online with data on user's device and if it's not the same then I am displaying a button to download content. After actions connected to this button I'd like to refresh the whole tableview to complare again the content online with local one.

`reloadData` does in fact update values but it doesn't remove these buttons. I'd like to change the way cells are displayed..

In other words I want this condition (in `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`) to work and it doesnt:

```
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:someDir isDirectory:nil]) {   
        UIButton *bt = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        (...)
        [cell addSubview:bt];
    }
```

To update the table now I have to pop the viewcontroller and push it again. I'd like to do it with button on navBar.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you're using a custom UITableViewCell, make sure you implement the method for preparing the cell for reuse, it's a problem with dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier. The cells with a button needs their own identifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you are caching cells with `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`. Check the docs. You should cache 2 types of cells, with and without the button.

Comment: so in short words, instead of adding button or not I should choose which one of 2 types of cell is supposed to be displayed?

Comment: Yes, pass a different identifier to dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier based on what cell you want. And create one with a button and one without.

Answer (score 1):

```
UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: @"your-id"];
if (cell)
{
     //Check if it should contain a button. If it shouldn't remove it
}
else
     //Create a fresh new cell
```